# Align header bottom

Tags: html, css

I moved my wordpress site to a new domain and now for some strange reason the layout is slightly altered.

Within header element there are divs logo and main-navigation. Logo used to be aligned with the bottom of main navigation but now it floats at the top.

Tried fiddling with margins, align and display but cannot get it.

Here is the gist of html:

```
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/">
      <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/cropped-75021.png" width="736" height="118" alt="Patchwood logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- end of #logo -->
  <div id="main-navigation">
    <div class="social-icons">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/trashswag">
            <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/orbit/images/twitter-icon.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Twitter url ">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/patchwood.reclaimed.wood">
            <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/orbit/images/facebook-icon.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Facebook url ">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <div class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal">
        <ul id="menu-main" class="main-nav l_tinynav1">
          <li id="menu-item-132" class="first-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-132">
            <a href="http://example.com/">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-154" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-154">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/patchwork/">
              Patchwork
            </a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-150">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/clear-outs-offers/">
              Clear Outs &amp; Offers
            </a>
          </li>
```

Possibly relevant CSS:

```
#logo {
display: inline;
float: left;
width: 40%;
margin: 0 1.0416666666666665%;
margin-bottom: 2.25%;

#main-navigation {
display: inline;
float: left;
width: 55%;
margin: 0 1.0416666666666665%;
```

(leaving out line item and anchor css probably not relevant? Too granular and maybe the issue is at sibling elements #logo and #main-navigation?)

You can see it here: http://tinyurl.com/7ywoqpf

I just want the logo to align at the bottom of it's parent element so appears. Here's a pic, I've added `* {outline: 1px solid}` to see better - I just want the logo aligned at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your CSS a little bit for your `logo` div and the `navigation` div like this:

```
#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    width: 40%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#main-navigation {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    width: 55%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[image]

You can also vertically align the logo and the navigation menu in the middle by using `vertical-align: middle` instead.

Comment: Many thanks, presumably valign does not work against a block element?

Comment: @dougfirr nope, it doesn't.